# '.' is not recognized as internal or external command?

Tags: angular, npm-run

**Problem:**

In my angular project, I have these flowing command in my package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "start:prod": "npm run build:prod && npm run server",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "test": "ng lint && ng test --configuration=test",
    "watch": "ng test --configuration=test --browsers ChromeHeadless --watch --reporters dots",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "e2e:ci": "ng e2e --webdriver-update false",
    "pree2e:ci": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=62.0.3202",
    "ci": "npm run format:test && ng lint && ng test --configuration=test --browsers ChromeTravisCi --code-coverage && npm run e2e:ci && npm run build:prod -- --deploy-url /angular-ngrx-material-starter/ --base-href /angular-ngrx-material-starter",
    "format:write": "prettier projects/**/*.{ts,json,md,scss} --write",
    "format:test": "prettier projects/**/*.{ts,json,md,scss} --list-different",
    "release": "standard-version && git push --follow-tags origin master",
    "analyze": "npm run build:prod -- --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer ./dist/angular-ngrx-material-starter/stats-es2015.json",
    "server": "node ./projects/server/server.js",
    "contributors:add": "all-contributors add",
    "contributors:generate": "all-contributors generate && node .all-contributors-html.js",
    "contributors:check": "all-contributors check"
  },
```

But when I try to run `npm run pree2e:ci` it is giving me this error.  `.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`. I search a lot but I was unable to find a valid reason. When I just hit this command on the bash it is working. `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=62.0.3202`. But when I just run npm run command it is not working. Can someone help me with this issue? . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
"./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=62.0.3202"
```

By see into the documentation : [link](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/legacy/docs/versions.md#download-a-specific-version)

```
"./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager clean && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 62.0.3202"
```

Comment: Still the same issue. When I just copy the command and run with bash it works fine but only failed with npm run

Comment: and maybe remove ./node_modules/protractor/bin/